# Sufficient & necessary conditions for singular and general statements

Tags: logic, logical-positivism, falsifiability

In David Rynin's 1956 address to the American Philosophical Association, "[Vindication of L*G*C*L P*S*T*V*SM](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3129288)", he remarks upon the "tenuous logical relationship" between a general statement, *"For any substance there exists some solvent"* and a singular statement, *"Substance A is a soluble in Substance B"*.

He comments that tho a name is not important, he is at a loss for a suitable name for this kind of logical relationship. Specifically he is pointing out that while the singular statement describes a sufficient condition for the satisfaction of a necessary condition, it does not describe a necessary condition for the general statements necessary condition, and therefore the general statement is not a strictly falsifiable hypothesis.

How then to describe this tenuous relationship?

---

EDIT: if you register w/Jstor, their basic & free membership allows access to articles (for a limited time, like two weeks iirc). This article by David Rynin (former Professor Emeritus @ UCBerkeley) is one of the ones freely available. Apologies as I am not trying to spam for Jstor, but he is an excellent author and otherwise difficult to find online without co$t.

Comment: It seems to me that we can cosnider it a particular case of [instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation) : perhaps a "double instantiation". From : **∀x∃yPxy** we derive : **∃yPay**. We may translate it as : "substance **a** is *soluble*". Then we verify the solubility of **a** producing a substance **b** such that **Pab** holds.

Comment: Rynin himself says that the name is not important, and later describes it verbosely as "*existence of a sufficient condition for the satisfaction of a
 necessary condition*". The issue is that even if S(x,y) is an empirically testable predicate its mixed quantification ∀x∃yS(x,y) has neither necessary nor sufficient truth conditions, i.e. it is neither verifiable nor falsifiable. Both would require testing universal claims (every substance, no solvent).  But basing meaningfulness on empirical verifiability popular with logical positivists is now considered unworkable, so the problem is moot.

Comment: @Conifold, and what little philosophers would speak of without "moot problems"? ;)

Comment: They upload them into richer frameworks. In this case the discussion moved to distinguishing aspects of scientific theories that are holons (empirical in some indirect way) from floaters (empirically idle) , see [Bonilla's Meaning and Testability in the Structuralist Theory of Science (2003)](http://www2.uned.es/dpto_log/jpzb/docs/Meaning.pdf)

Comment: @Conifold good stuff there from Jesus. Not so interested in frameworks, myself but I appreciate the richness you speak of with a respect formed by poverty.

Comment: @Conifold if you put your comments in an answer I'd likely accept it as is but especially if you made a point pertaining to uploading the description of the "tenuous"" relationship into a "richer framework"

Comment: @Conifold honestly though, I don't really think structuralism and what Rynin is discussing jive. Rynin's apples to Bonilla's apple-flavorings.